# Intellij running multiple kotlin files inside project, instead the one selected

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

Learning Kotlin and IntelliJ,

Before yesterday if I wanted to run one single .kt file, it was all good. Many ways to do it.
I was doing various exercises, all in the same file exercises.kt. After finishing a code, I would just transform it into a comment and start the next one in the same file.

After many exercises, I decided to create a .kt file for each one. But, now, when I run a single file for one exercise Intellij is running ALL files inside the project, instead of just the one I selected.

EDIT: Every .kt file got its own main function, some with a class. To run a single file I used different methods. Clicking the play button at the left of the main function, or clicking the play button at the top bar with the current file selected and clicling with the right button on top of the file in the project list and selecting "Run filekt" (Same as Ctrt + shift + F10). Like I said before the change explained it was all good.

Here it is my run configuration:

[image: Run Configuration]

Content of one of my files that was single running before I changed

```
fun main() {
    val amanda = Person("Amanda", 33, "play tennis", null)
    val atiqah = Person("Atiqah", 28, "climb", amanda)

    amanda.showProfile()
    atiqah.showProfile()
}

class Person(val name: String, val age: Int, val hobby: String?, val referrer: Person?) {
    fun showProfile() {
        when {
            referrer == null -> println("""Name: ${name}
Age: ${age}
Likes to ${hobby}. Doesn't have a referrer."""")
            else -> println("""Name: ${name}
Age: ${age}
Likes to ${hobby}. Has a referrer named ${referrer.name}, who likes to ${referrer.hobby}""")
        }
    }
}
```

When Intellij run all the files, this is showing in the project errors. This is new as well. If I try to run the SongCatalog files on Kotlin Playground it's all good.(The Special Auction is in progress)

[image: ProjectError]

For the rest of the files, here's the repository: [Google Learning Repo](https://github.com/rafaover/GoogleLearning)

Comment: Edited the post with more details @Sweeper, like suggested. Thank you.

Comment: The way you are doing it wouldn't *run* all the files in the project, but it would *compile* all the files in the project. For example, compiler errors in one file would prevent you from running other files. Did you confuse compiling with running? What makes you think you are "running" all the files in the project?

Comment: @Sweeper I've added the project error image. I said running because that's what is said on the button. But, yeah. Compile. I thought IntelliJ would run only the main function selected if I clicked using the correct configuration. But maybe after I changed the files something got mixed. Some kt that before was working inside the exercises.kt now is not working anymore (despite it working in kotlin playground).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ does not *run* all the files. It *compiles* all the files, but only runs the file that you specified in the run configuration.

However, since two of your files, SongCatalog.kt and SongCatalog2.kt, both declare a `SongCatalog` class, there is a compiler error. The same class cannot be declared twice, after all. Even if you are just trying to run some other file, all the files in your project has to be compiled.

## Using Packages

I recommend just putting each exercise that you are doing in its package. This way the two `SongCatalog`s are distinct. For example, at the start of SongCatalog.kt, you can write:

```
package exercise4_1
```

and at the start of SongCatalog2.kt, you can write:

```
package exercise4_2
```

Put each file into a folder with the same name as the package. Do this for all the other files containing your exercises so that it's organised.

Make sure that IntelliJ don't automatically insert `import`s, importing things from other exercises, causing conflicts again.

Then in your run configuration, write add the package name as a prefix for the main class. For example, to run SongCatalog.kt, you'd write `exercise4_1.SongCatalogKt`.

---

## Using Modules

There is also another rather overkill method of having IntelliJ only compile a part of your project's files. You can put each of your exercises' files into a different module.

To add a module, go to File -> New -> Module. Then you can give that module a name and add new .kt files to the /src folder of that module.

[image]

[image]

Configure your run configuration the same way as before, except choose the module that you want to run in the "use class path of module" dropdown.

Comment: I was writing about the duplicate class when I saw your reply. I did I second way to solve the song catalogue and forgot about this. That solved. 

But Thank you very much for the package information, I'm gonna read about it before moving around. I think when you talk about folder, you're talking about the "Package folder". I

Comment: The module is exactly what I need. Going to test all that and check how it works. Thanks very much for the masterclass. :)